# Rails - Mess with migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

I'm hoping someone can help me sort this out without having to re-create my entire backend.

I'm using Rails and was having trouble deploying to Heroku. When I ran

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

my migration failed, because I had a migration that dropped a table that didn't exist. What had happened is that I had a table called Relations, and renamed it to SchoolCityType (**singular**).

This migration that dropped the table was dropping SchoolCityType**s** (**plural, as it should be**).

Problem: I deleted the migration file instead of rolling it back, but Heroku still won't run the command.

What should I do? Thanks in advance.

heroku migration error message:

```
== 20160407014126 DropSchoolDistrictCityTypesTable: migrating =================
-- drop_table(:school_district_city_types)
   (1.7ms)  DROP TABLE "school_district_city_types"
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "school_district_city_types" does not exist
: DROP TABLE "school_district_city_types"
   (1.1ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:`== 20160407014126 DropSchoolDistrictCityTypesTable: migrating =================
-- drop_table(:school_district_city_types)
   (1.7ms)  DROP TABLE "school_district_city_types"
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "school_district_city_types" does not exist
: DROP TABLE "school_district_city_types"
   (1.1ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "school_district_city_types" does not exist
: DROP TABLE "school_district_city_types"
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:116:in `drop_table'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20160407014126_drop_school_district_city_types_table.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "school_district_city_types" does not exist
: DROP TABLE "school_district_city_types"
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:116:in `drop_table'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20160407014126_drop_school_district_city_types_table.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "school_district_city_types" does not exist
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:116:in `drop_table'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20160407014126_drop_school_district_city_types_table.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate`
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. If you deleted the migration file, there should be no problem. Please include the error message from Heroku's logs.

Comment: I've just added it. Thanks

Comment: According to the logs, `20160407014126_drop_school_district_city_types_table` still exists and is trying to drop your table. If the table no longer exists in any of your database, you can simply delete that file. If you want to maintain the migration because some instances of your application might have that database, you can simply create an empty table with the correct name on Heroku so the migration can complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

you can still rollback even if you delete your migrations.

I suggest you rollback to a position you're comfortable with and work from there with new migrations.

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like you have deleted the migration file which creates 'school_district_city_types'. You are now trying to delete the table which does not exist/created before. Simply just delete the migration file '20160407014126' which drops that table.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just delete the migration file.  In the future write your migrations like this:

```
drop_table :school_district_city_types if (table_exists? :school_district_city_types)
```

and you will never have this issue again.